# Get Object properties of selected list item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a listbox that has a listsource that is a list of 'results' objects. The results class looks like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__I { get; set; }
    public string FN { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string SEX { get; set; }
    public string SN { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__U { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }        

    //Gender icon path associated with result
    public string SexIcon { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what my listbox looks like in the xaml code:

```
<ListBox 
            Height="517" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="12,84,0,0" 
            Name="searchList" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="438" 
            SelectionChanged="SearchList_SelectedEvent">

            <!-- What each listbox item will look like -->
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                        
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Sex, Converter={StaticResource SexToSourceConverter}}" Visibility="Visible" />                            
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Name="FirstName" Text="{Binding FN}" FontSize="28" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="LastName" Text="{Binding SN}" FontSize="28" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DOB}" FontSize="24" />
                            <!-- Line Stroke="#FF04863C" StrokeThickness="3" X1="100" Y1="100" X2="300" Y2="100" / -->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>                            
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

So my question is, (and what I'm really struggling with) is how does one for instance get the value of the GUID property of the selected Item (which is basically a results object)?

Comment: Please check this tutorial [comment for help](https://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/#comment-343)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(searchList.SelectedItem as Result).GUID

Comment: Thanks! But just to clarify, do I use this in my  listBox SelectionChanged="SearchList_SelectedEvent"??

Comment: I just answered my own question there... yes, I use it in my listBoxs's SelectinoChange event.