# How to get object of list after object's property has been updated in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm making a ListView filled with List of objects, which properties are shown and editable in a ListView. I need to get object when its properties are being updated. How can I do this?

I tried creating an object of class and bind it to SelectedItem in ListView. The problem is that, obviously, the SelectedItem is set after clicking the row of ListItem, but not the children of that row. I need to get the updated object from the row of my ListView each time after any ComboBox or TextBox values are changed.

To handle all the things with INotifyPropertyChanged I'm using PropertyChanged.Fody. Could it help me to solve this problem easier?

**View**

[Appearance of the ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFIQ7.png)

```
<ListView 
        Margin="10"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TimesheetEntries}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntry, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" Margin="3">
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="Auto" 
                        Margin="10"/>
                    <ComboBox 
                        SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding EmploymentTypesDictionary, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEmployment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Width="270"/>
                    <TextBox 
                        Text="{Binding Hours, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        Margin="10,0,0,0"
                        Width="70"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public List<TimesheetEntryEntity> TimesheetEntries
{
    get { return _TimesheetEntries; }
    set { _TimesheetEntries = value; }
}

public TimesheetEntryEntity SelectedEntry
{
    get { return _SelectedEntry; }
    set { _SelectedEntry = value; }
}
```

...

```
private List<TimesheetEntryEntity> _TimesheetEntries { get; set; }
private TimesheetEntryEntity _SelectedEntry;
private TimesheetModel timesheetModel;
public TimesheetViewModel()
{
        this.Timesheets = TimesheetUnitModel.GetAllTimesheetsForUnit((int)Application.Current.Properties["UnitID"]);
        this._StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        _TimesheetEntries = new List<TimesheetEntryEntity>();
}
public KeyValuePair<int, string> SelectedWorker
{
    get { return _SelectedWorker; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedWorker = value;
        _TimesheetEntries =
                timesheetModel.GetTimesheetList(_SelectedWorker.Key, SelectedTimesheet.Key, StartDate.Date);
    }
}
```

**TimesheetEntryEntity**

```
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<EmploymentTypes, string> EmploymentTypesDictionary { get; set; }

    public EmploymentTypes SelectedEmployment {
        get { return _SelectedEmployment; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedEmployment = value;
            CheckHoursAvaliability();
        }
    }
    public bool HoursAvaliable { get; set; }

    public decimal Hours
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private EmploymentTypes _SelectedEmployment;

    public TimesheetEntryEntity()
    {
        FillEmploymentTypes();
    }

    public void FillEmploymentTypes()
    {
        //Some code here
    }
```

I tried to follow the answer from [Get Object properties of selected list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412957/get-object-properties-of-selected-list-item) question, but there were only textblocks, so the row gets selected anyway, but i have ComboBox and TextBox, who get their own focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your TimesheetEntryEntity i.e.

```
public abstract class TimesheetEntryEntity: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler Changed;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public void OnChange()
    {
        EventHandler handler = Changed;
        handler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private DateTime date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => date;
        set
        {
            if (date == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            //Do something with unchanged property
            date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            OnChange();
            //Do something with changed property
        }
    }
```

in your ViewModel before adding new item to list:

```
   timesheet.Changed+=ItemChanged;
```

and

```
 private void ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var item=sender as TimesheetEntryEntity;
       //do something    
    }
```

Comment: I get the pre-filled List from my model, so I had to assign the event for each object after getting the list in the ViewModel with `foreach`. But it works flawlessly, thanks.